# Argument parser with mixed type of args input in Python's argparse module

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following script:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-s",metavar="",help="some help",type=int,default=0.5)
print parser.parse_args()
```

The 3rd line, I'd like to have the type of `int` and `string`. So the user can use one of these values `[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 'best']`.

How can I do that?

Comment: why not just take in a string and try casts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `type` argument can be considered as a convert function instead of data type.

So you can add a converter like this:

```
def int_or_str(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except:
        return value
```

and pass as `type`.

Comment: what do you mean `pass as 'type'`. If I do it your way, what value should I give to `type`?

Comment: @neversaint `type=int_ot_str`

Comment: @neversaint I just put my code on top of your code and replace `type=int` as `type=int_ot_str`, it works.

Comment: running example in ipython, please. I got `NameError: global name 'in_ot_str' is not defined`.

Comment: @eph The question actually includes `0.3` which is a `float` not an `int`.

Comment: The `type` IS the convert function.  It's an unfortunate consequence of the name that people think of it as the target data type.